# Not able to run project

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios

I have selected Location in Xcode preference also but getting the same error:

[image]

```
xcrun: error: Failed to determine realpath of '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk' (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH

Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
xcrun: error: Failed to determine realpath of '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk' (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH

Error: Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
xcrun: error: Failed to determine realpath of '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk' (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH

at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:621:13)
at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/ranjith/Documents/Project/Login_React/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:76:17)
at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/ranjith/Documents/Project/Login_React/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:117:22)
at <anonymous>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at that path ? It seems you might have to install a specific iPhone simulator : iOS 11.4

Answer (score 7):

[image: Xcode Preferences]

Check Xcode Command Line Tools are configured Correctly go following path

> Open Xcode > Preferences > Locations
>
> Then Set the Command Line Tools

Comment: thank you :) I did already that but there is no problem, I rectified that now it's working i used npm add @babel/runtime , npm install --save react-native@0.57.1 and then react-native run-ios

Answer (score 4):

In my case, an Xcode update caused iPhoneOS-12.2.sdk to be no longer available; instead, the path contained iPhoneOS-12.4.sdk. But `react-native run-ios` complained of not being able to find `12.2`.

Restarting the computer fixed the issue.

Comment: Amazing that this can still be the solution in 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have XCode and Command Line Tools installed?

Comment: Thank you, Yes it's there and I rectified that now it's working i used npm add @babel/runtime , npm install --save react-native@0.57.1 and then react-native run-ios